# php random mysql data

Tags: php, mysql, random

I have a MySQL database with 6 columns in a table. There will eventually be about 100 rows, for now I have 3.

Column titles: FirstName, SecondName, Sentence1, Sentence2, Sentence3, Sentence4

All tables are set to VARCHAR

**I want to use php on a web page to call random data from each row, eg mix and match row1 FirstName with row3 SecondName and row2 Sentence1 etc.**

I read it is quicker to randomise using php but I really can't grasp how to do this despite searching.

I can connect to my MySQL database and get results returned using this code:

```
    <?php
    // Connect to database server
    mysql_connect("localhost", "xxx", "yyy") or die (mysql_error ());
    // Select database
    mysql_select_db("zzz") or die(mysql_error());
    // SQL query
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Users";
    // Execute the query (the recordset $rs contains the result)
    $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
    // Loop the recordset $rs
    // Each row will be made into an array ($row) using mysql_fetch_array
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    // Write the value of the column FirstName (which is now in the array $row)
    echo $row['FirstName'] . "<br />";
      }
    // Close the database connection
    mysql_close();
    ?>
```

but this just returns one column of data. I need the random code to be returned in the webpage using something like:

```
echo $firstname . $lastname . $sentence1 . $sentence2 . $sentence3 . $sentence4;
```

Note, this will be repeated for another 3 or 4 rows afterwards too

```
echo $firstname_2 . $lastname_2 . $sentence1_2 . $sentence2_2 . $sentence3_2 . $sentence4_2;
```

I'm not too hot on arrays but if someone can get me started it would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All those telling you to use rand in the SQL query have not read the question. To those people: the asker wants a random combination of data from the rows, not a random row.

Something like this. It will take all the results from the database and echo a totally random combination. I couldn't avoid using arrays as they are super useful.

```
<?php
// Connect to database server
mysql_connect("localhost", "xxx", "yyy") or die (mysql_error ());
// Select database
mysql_select_db("zzz") or die(mysql_error());
// SQL query
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Users";
// Execute the query (the recordset $rs contains the result)
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
// Array to hold all data
$rows = array();
// Loop the recordset $rs
// Each row will be made into an array ($row) using mysql_fetch_array
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
// add row to array.
$rows[] = $row;
  }
// Close the database connection
mysql_close();

// Max rand number
$max = count($rows) - 1;

// print out random combination of data.
echo $rows[rand(0, $max)][0] . " " . $rows[rand(0, $max)][1] . " " . $rows[rand(0, $max)][2] . " " . $rows[rand(0, $max)][3] . " " . $rows[rand(0, $max)][4] . " " . $rows[rand(0, $max)][5];

?>
```

Comment: +1 for actually reading the question! (and for pipping me to the post by 3 minutes)

Comment: That's nice Matthew and it works well thanks. The only thing I need to know now is if it can be called later on in the webpage php without connecting to the database again?

Comment: Yeah it can. All the data has been stored in the $rows variable.

Comment: Also, @Sara44, people will be more likely to answer any future questions you may have if you accept an answer by clicking the green tick to the top left of the desired post.

Comment: Sorry Matthew, thought I had done that. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Store all the values which you want to show in random in a variable, use rand() http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php and shuffle() http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php to make the random data and display them

Answer (score 2):

there are several methods to get random data from db in php

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1;
```

another method: -

```
$range_result = mysql_query( " SELECT MAX(`id`) AS max_id , MIN(`id`) AS min_id FROM    `table` ");
$range_row = mysql_fetch_object( $range_result ); 
$random = mt_rand( $range_row->min_id , $range_row->max_id );
$result = mysql_query( " SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` >= $random LIMIT 0,1 ");
```

one more method:-

```
$offset_result = mysql_query( " SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) AS `offset` FROM `table` ");
$offset_row = mysql_fetch_object( $offset_result ); 
$offset = $offset_row->offset;
$result = mysql_query( " SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT $offset, 1 " );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `Users` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1;
```

Comment: This is not what was asked though. They want a random combination of data fields from the rows, not just a random row.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ORDER BY RAND()` for random records selection.

Answer (score 1):

Split it into two tables,
one for the user

Users:
id | firstname | lastname

Sentences:
id | userId | sentence

Join both at the "id / userId" and do a ORDER BY RAND() probably followed by a LIMIT 20

Answer (score 1):

Trying to implement this but taking an entry from every column (14 at present) instead of a small random number. Would love to have Matthew McGovern's opinion since his code suited me except that it only called a few entries...

Here: [Random Sentence Using PHP & MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561543/random-sentence-using-php-mysql)